# Знаки вопроса из MySQL

Tags: mysqli

Проблема с выводом из БД. Везде utf-8. База utf8_general_ci . Вот код.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
 </head>
<body>
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_init();


if (!$mysqli->real_connect('localhost', 'roly', 'O1z6H7v8', 'sushiris')) {
    die('Ошибка подключения (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') ' . mysqli_connect_error());
    mysql_query("SET NAMES utf-8");
}




$products = array();
if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM products')) {
    while($tmp = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $products[] = $tmp;
    }
    $result->close();
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
<div class="row">
    <?php foreach($products AS $product) {?>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 <?php echo $product['filter'];?>">
            <div class="thumbnail">
            <h4><?php echo $product['title'];?></h4>
                <img src="<?php echo $product['img'];?>" alt="" width="200">
                <div class="caption">
                    <h4 class="pull-right"><?php echo $product['price'];?> грн</h4>
                    <p><?php echo $product['description'];?></p>
                    <p>Ссылка - #win<?php echo $product['id'];?></p>
                </div>
                <div class="ratings">
                    <p class="pull-right">Вес: <?php echo $product['weight'];?>гр</p>

                 </div>
            </div>
       </div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Не могу понять почему везде знаки вопроса http://sushi.sushiris.kiev.ua/index-s.php

Comment: В phpMyAdmin таблица нормально отображается?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте указать кодировку работы с базой после установления соединения.

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

Естественно кодировка базы, таблицы и полей должна быть идентичной, равно как у файла скрипта. А также необходимо задать кодировку по умолчанию.

**.htaccess**

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

**nginx**

```
charset UTF-8;
```

Comment: Да всё уже перепробовал
данные в таблицах в utf8_general_ci

Comment: Благодарю
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
это помогло

Comment: @allaurross не пробовать нужно, а взять в привычку по умолчанию использовать во всём единую кодировку. И не важно какую. Тут больше вопрос насколько она будет удовлетворять вашим поставленным задачам.

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте в начало

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Comment: Добавлял это , безрезультатно

Comment: попробуйте в мета прописать ‘windows-1251’